# tikzscale not working with subcaptionbox?

Tags: tikz-pgf, subcaption, tikzscale

I have some complicated `tikz` pictures that I don't want to manually resize (therefore `tikzscale`) - but putting several in a figure doesn't seem to work with `\subcaptionbox`. It *does* work with `subfigure` (also from the `subcaption` package), but then the captions are not aligned if the number of lines per caption differ.

For the MWE one needs to create a `square.tikz`-file with the following content (obviously this is a simplification to illustrate the problem ;-))

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-10,-10) rectangle (10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then the code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \subcaptionbox{One-line caption}[0.5\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{square.tikz}}
    \subcaptionbox{Two-line caption \\ is aligned}[0.5\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{square.tikz}}
    \caption{With \texttt{subcaptionbox}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{square.tikz}
        \caption{One-line caption}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{square.tikz}
        \caption{Two-line caption; \\ should be aligned with one-line caption}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{With \texttt{subfigure}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{square.tikz}` is better be `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{square.tikz}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `subfigure` environment is actually a `minipage` where `\textwidth` is reset to the stated width. The same is not true for `\subcaptionbox`; the optional argument to `\subcaptionbox` is not required, if you just want it has the same dimension as the object inside.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{square.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-10,-10) rectangle (10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{One-line caption}{%
  \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{square.tikz}%
}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Two-line caption \\ is aligned}{%
  \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{square.tikz}%
}

\caption{With \texttt{subcaptionbox}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since `subfigure` needs a width (and `includegraphics` needs to do the work of resizing for `tikzscale`), it didn't occur to me to use `subcaptionbox` without the optional argument. It just caught me off-guard that the same construction didn't work - I guess I should have experimented more before asking.